# Populate select box options of a objectbrick, dynamically

Tags: pimcore

I have a class "groups", that have many objects.
for example "All","Mobile","Watches".

We have select box in a objectbrick. we want to populate select box with the objects of "groups" class.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible out of the box but can be done with the help of this plugin:
https://github.com/ThomasKeil/pimcore-plugin-DynamicDropdown

To install the plugin do these steps:

- within /plugins folder create a new folder called DynamicDropdown
- on this page https://github.com/ThomasKeil/pimcore-plugin-DynamicDropdown download the zip of the plugin
- extract contents of the zip to the folder created in the first step (so that the DynamicDropdown includes folders: controllers, lib, static, texts, views, ...)
- in the administration backend go to Tools (Wrench icon) > Extensions
- enable the plugin
- reload Pimcore backend
- go to ObjectBricks and add the DynamicDropdown field to the ObjectBrick
- in the field settings you should then pick the folder with objects that provide the options, the Object Class of the options and which method is used for the display values

I think the plugin config is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks @Igor, I will try it.

Comment: Hello @Igore, I am very new to pimcore. Can You please explain steps to implement this plugin over objectbrick.

Comment: @Archana I updated my answer with instructions on how to install the plugin, I think the config options of the plugin are self-explanatory.

Comment: @Igore, thanks for response. I installed plugin and enabled it, But when I am adding **DynamicDropdown field**, it is giving error **Some fields cannot be saved**. I am able to add other type of field. Is there any issue with permission or pimcore version.

Comment: @Igore Issue is found, Issue was with parent id. But still not getting response. Excution stop when come to $folder = Object_Folder::getByPath($parentFolderPath); Line. Here Object_Folder does not exist in  pimcore lib.

Comment: @igore, I did it. :). But my issue still exist because dynamic dropdown changing my current database structure. I need to do it manually.

Comment: @Archana sorry, I don't understand. In what way is DynamicDropdown changing the database structure?

Comment: @Igore thanks for reply, I did it by other way. I was trying to implement dynamic dropdown on alredy exist select box. So when I implemented dynamic dropdown, class definition changed, because of class definition changed, field value flushed from database.

Comment: @Igore Oh, I see what you mean now. Yes, you need to replace select field with the DynamicDropdown. But I'm glad you managed to solve your issue.

Comment: Hello @Igore, To make dynamic drp manually, I override objectbrick **pimcore.object.tags.objectbricks**  and call loadFieldDefinitions on postOpenObject. It is working fine. But issue occur when object open for first time. When I open object after login. It is showing old values, but if I reload object then it shows new option values.

Answer (score 1):

Pimcore X has this function out of the box.
Just provide a class to 'Options Provider Class or Service Name:' property.

Sample:

```
public function getOptions($context, $fieldDefinition)
{
    $object = isset($context["object"]) ? $context["object"] : null;
    if (!$object) {
        return [];
    }
    $groups = $object->getGroups();        
    $result = [];
    foreach ($groups as $name => $group) {
        $result[] = ["key" => $group->getTitle() . ' (' . $name . ')', "value" => $name];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

if you need to get all allowedObjectBricks, which are coupled with current object using the field 'someObjectBricks', then try the following:

```
        $productBricks = $object->getSomeObjectBricks();
        $objectBricksNames = $productBricks->getAllowedBrickTypes();
        foreach ($objectBricksNames as $name) {
            try {
                $definitions = Objectbrick\Definition::getByKey($name);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                continue;
            }
        }
```

See the documentation
https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/current/Development_Documentation/Objects/Object_Classes/Data_Types/Dynamic_Select_Types.html